# RESTful WCF Service returns a 400 code when sending form-data parameters

Tags: c#, wcf, post, wcf-data-services

i 'm trying to call a post method via Postman

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Login"]
string Login(string host, string user, string pass, string applicationId);
public string Login(string host, string user, string pass, string applicationId)
{
    int res= new login().Loginn(host, user, pass, applicationId);
    if (res == 1)
        return "Connected";
    else
        return "Failed";
}
```

whene i  pass those parameters via Postman in body request form-data the response is 400 bad request

whene i change to application/json and i put a json string in raws it works .

is there any solution to use body form-data request please whithout using one parameter with stream type 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a custom [message formatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageformatter.aspx) that will understand the form-urlencoded input and convert that into the parameters of your operation. The post at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/endpoint/2011/05/03/wcf-extensibility-message-formatters/ has a lot of informations about formatters, and the code below shows a simple implementation of such a formatter that can deal with form data.

```
public class StackOverflow_35921627
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string Login(string host, string user, string pass, string applicationId);
    }

    public class Service : ITest
    {
        public string Login(string host, string user, string pass, string applicationId)
        {
            return string.Format("Login result: {0} - {1} - {2} - {3}", host, user, pass, applicationId);
        }
    }

    public class MyWebHttpBehavior : WebHttpBehavior
    {
        protected override IDispatchMessageFormatter GetRequestDispatchFormatter(OperationDescription operationDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
            var originalFormatter = base.GetRequestDispatchFormatter(operationDescription, endpoint);
            return new FormDataDispatchFormatter(operationDescription, originalFormatter);
        }
    }

    public class FormDataDispatchFormatter : IDispatchMessageFormatter
    {
        IDispatchMessageFormatter originalFormatter;
        Dictionary<string, int> parameterNames;

        public FormDataDispatchFormatter(OperationDescription operation, IDispatchMessageFormatter originalFormatter)
        {
            var inputMessageBodyParts = operation.Messages[0].Body.Parts;
            this.parameterNames = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < inputMessageBodyParts.Count; i++)
            {
                if (inputMessageBodyParts[i].Type == typeof(string))
                {
                    // For now, only support string parameters; others will be ignored
                    this.parameterNames.Add(inputMessageBodyParts[i].Name, i);
                }
            }

            this.originalFormatter = originalFormatter;
        }


        public void DeserializeRequest(Message message, object[] parameters)
        {
            object httpRequestProperty;
            if (!message.Properties.TryGetValue(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, out httpRequestProperty))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("This formatter can only be used with HTTP");
            }

            var contentType = ((HttpRequestMessageProperty)httpRequestProperty).Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType];
            if (contentType == null || !contentType.StartsWith("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))
            {
                this.originalFormatter.DeserializeRequest(message, parameters);
                return;
            }

            object bodyFormatProperty;
            if (!message.Properties.TryGetValue(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name, out bodyFormatProperty) ||
                (bodyFormatProperty as WebBodyFormatMessageProperty).Format != WebContentFormat.Raw)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Incoming messages must have a body format of Raw. Is a ContentTypeMapper set on the WebHttpBinding?");
            }

            XmlDictionaryReader bodyReader = message.GetReaderAtBodyContents();
            bodyReader.ReadStartElement("Binary");
            byte[] rawBody = bodyReader.ReadContentAsBase64();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(rawBody);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
            string formData = sr.ReadToEnd();

            string[] parts = formData.Split('&');
            foreach (var part in parts)
            {
                // TODO: handle url-decoding

                var kvp = part.Split('=');
                if (kvp.Length != 2)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Only support simple parameters for now");
                }

                int index;
                if (this.parameterNames.TryGetValue(kvp[0], out index))
                {
                    parameters[index] = kvp[1];
                }
            }
        }

        public Message SerializeReply(MessageVersion messageVersion, object[] parameters, object result)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("This is a request-only formatter");
        }
    }

    internal static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        ServiceEndpoint endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MyWebHttpBehavior());
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        SendPostRequest(baseAddress + "/Login", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "host=myHost&user=myUser&pass=myPassword&applicationId=app123");

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }

    static void SendPostRequest(string url, string contentType, string body)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = contentType;
        byte[] bodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
        Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        reqStream.Write(bodyBytes, 0, bodyBytes.Length);
        reqStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse resp;
        try
        {
            resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            resp = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
        }

        if (resp == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Response is null");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HTTP/{0} {1} {2}", resp.ProtocolVersion, (int)resp.StatusCode, resp.StatusDescription);
            foreach (string headerName in resp.Headers.AllKeys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", headerName, resp.Headers[headerName]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Stream respStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
            if (respStream != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(respStream).ReadToEnd());
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream returned null");
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("  *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*  ");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```